# Why does Windows 8 refuse to connect to my WiFi repeater even though it has a much stronger signal than the access point it repeats?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wireless-access-point, repeater

I recently installed a WiFi repeater in my small business. It is truly a "repeater" in that it does not broadcast a duplicate SSID or its own SSID, but rather is joined to the same SSID from the original WiFi access point.

I've noticed that Windows 8 seems to prefer the original access point even if I am physically right next to the repeater. To test my theory, I explicitly disabled my WiFi MAC address from the original WiFi access point. My signal strength went from 3 bars to 5, and the repeater's GUI indicated that my WiFi card was connected (by showing a table of MAC addresses). As soon as I removed the MAC restriction from the original WiFi access point, my signal strength dropped again and my MAC address was no longer in the repeater's table.

Why is this happening, and how can I make Windows 8 choose the "best" access point based on signal strength?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* that the problem comes from the fact that Windows looks for known access points first, if it finds one it *can* connect to, it will. This can lead to unexpected consequences as you've seen. You might also see issues depending on which channels you've set the two different devices to.

Multi-AP Wi-Fi can be problematic. We see other problems even when using an expensive enterprise system such as those from CISCO. Such as stuck sessions where devices (particularly Apple mobile devices) get "stuck" in a dead session and cannot reconnect. We also have Windows Mobile devices that fall off the network and refuse to reconnect to anything until rebooted.

Home devices seem to be very hit and miss, your setup may work for a while and then start failing even though no changes have been made. Rebooting the AP's may help for a while but problems resurface later and are multiplied the more devices that connect.

In terms of fixing it, I don't think you can - I'm sure I'll be corrected if someone knows otherwise. What you *can* do is to publish two different SSID's and manually switch between them. After many trials and tribulations with home devices, that is what I do at home.

Comment: I also configured two different SSID's to solve a similar problem at home and at friends. Having only one SSID is best theoretically but in practice, it didn't work for me either.

Comment: Without getting too thick into the weeds... My testing and research has convinced me that unless you have a program installed on Windows to actively manage SSID to MAC address assignment, or perhaps a very creative L2 solution, it will never work reliably enough to justify wasting that second access point. Better to assign its own SSID as you said. I wonder if you could create AP's that communicate with each other over one WiFi interface and their WiFi clients over another so that they could share a single MAC address but have a way to maintain state and to map source MAC to appropriate ap